# variable value not retained after while loop

Tags: linux, unix, sh, heredoc, solaris-10

I am writing a loop which accumulates strings in a variable `def`, reading from a heredoc. I can't see the value of variable after the loop exits.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/sh

def=""
while read x; do
   def="$def -D$x"
   echo $def
done <<-COMMANDS_GREEN
hello="hello green world"
host="greenmen.com"
port=80
COMMANDS_GREEN

################### exit loop ########################
echo definition: $def
```

As the script output, inside the loop all. The **definition:** which is outside the loop doesn't show anything:

```
-Dhello="hello green world"
-Dhello="hello green world" -Dhost="greenmen.com"
-Dhello="hello green world" -Dhost="greenmen.com" -Dport=80
################### exit loop ########################
definition:
```

I am writing this under Solaris 10, not bash

Comment: What is the shell linked to `/usr/bin/sh` ? : Output of `ls -l /usr/bin/sh`

Comment: If you want POSIX compliance, use `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` - https://stackoverflow.com/q/3254589/10971581

Comment: cf. https://github.com/kofemann/opensolaris/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/sh/cmd.c#L489

Comment: @GillesQuénot Ooof.  I hope no one was "smart" enough to muck around with `/usr/bin/sh` on a Solaris system like that.  I'd consider such a person just smart enough to be dangerous, and be sorely tempted to terminate their access to `root` in any form.

Answer (score 1):

Changed to `ksh`, it solved the problem

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
```

thanks to @jhnc and @Gilles Quénot for info provided in comments